# Comparison of two self ratings

Tags: statistics, math-software, number-comparison

I have a small doubt regarding the comparison of two ratings.

I have two candidates, I asked them to rate themselves out of 10 in 4 different subjects. Both have the same level of knowledge in both subjects.

Student name Rating (Maths Physics Chemistry Biology)

A                    10    10      10        10
B                    7     7       7         7

(According to A he is giving 10/10 for his best skill, and B is giving 7/10 for his best skill.)

If I am comparing A and B in an absolute scale A is better than B. Is there a way or approach to detect them having the same skill? The only reference I have is the information in the table which is relative and I know they have the same skillset.

Please help me out,
Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks and regards,
Sarin

Comment: One important perspective for this, I think, is what those ratings are for, which generally helps to extract credible information. Since this is self-reporting, people's behavior should be based on, at least to some extent, their expectation on the outcome of their report. Also, other details like whether both candidates know the total number of candidates should have a bite.

Comment: I agree with you. Some relative understanding about rating between candidates will help here. But still wondering how to fill the gap between these two details.

Answer (score 1):

With self-ratings? I don't see any realistic way to use them to compare between different students. There's some credibility in comparing how a student rated themself in different subjects, but across different students? You have no way of telling what standards they're using. Also, all sorts of social effects apply.

That said, student A is almost certainly lying. Whether he's lying to you to get attention, or lying to himself that he doesn't have more to learn, I wouldn't trust those ratings at all. (Why did I switch to gendered pronouns? See social effects above.) With just these numbers to work with, and no other information about the candidates, I would rather work with student B.

And all this? It's more social science than anything. The mathematics of it doesn't really come in until we have some actual credible data.